# When considering comparisons for a Heap Sort, what exactly do you consider as a comparison?

Tags: algorithm, math, heapsort

I've coded up the Heap Sort algorithm, but I'm having a hard time deciding what should be considered a comparison. I assumed the following would contribute towards the comparisons but the results I obtain seem off to me (by a lot maybe?) here's the code

```
       public class heapsort{
      static int counter = 0;

      public static void main(String[] args) { 
         //int[] a1={1, 16, 2, 3, 14, 4, 5, 12, 7, 10, 8, 9, 17, 19, 21, 23, 26, 27}; 

            int[] a1 = {1, 2};
            System.out.println(sort(a1)); 
         for(int i=0;i<a1.length;i++){ 
            System.out.print(a1[i] + " "); 
         } 
      } 

      private static int[] a; 
      private static int n; 
      private static int left; 
      private static int right; 
      private static int largest;

      public static void buildheap(int[] a){ 
         n= a.length-1; 
         for(int i= n/2; i >= 0; --i){ 
            maxheap(a,i); 
         } 
      } 

      public static void maxheap(int[] a, int i){ 
         left=2*i; 
         right=2*i+1; 
         if(left <= n && a[left] > a[i]){ 
            counter++;
            largest=left; 
         } 
         else{ 
            counter++;
            largest=i; 
         } 

         if(right <= n && a[right] > a[largest]){ 
            counter++;

            largest=right; 
         } 
         if(largest!=i){ 
            counter++;     
            exchange(i,largest); 
            maxheap(a, largest); 
         } 
      } 

      public static void exchange(int i, int j){ 
         int t=a[i]; 
         a[i]=a[j]; 
         a[j]=t; 
      } 

      public static int sort(int []a0){ 
         a=a0; 
         buildheap(a); 

         for(int i=n;i>0; --i){ 
            exchange(0, i); 
            n=n-1; 
            maxheap(a, 0); 
         } 
         return counter;
      }       
   }
```

I know some of the counters might be wrong, suggestions?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here.

Comment: The point is to find out how efficient the algorithm is. When doing this by hand one has to do comparisons between the values in the array. When should I consider a comparison to occur so that I may add a +1 to my comparison count? This is in order to find the best case and worst case for the algorithm

Comment: Ok; nothing in your question described the fact that you're trying to **count** comparisons.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I wish I could highlight it, but just try reading the first sentence.

Comment: Yes, I read that, but nothing in that sentence implies **counting**.

Comment: I thought that logically the code would suggest I'm counting the comparison.

Comment: Maybe.  But no-one is going to think to trawl through all that code to figure out what you are asking about ;)

Comment: @Ceelos Unfortunately, number of comparisons isn't a terribly useful measure of a sort's efficiency in the real world.  Can you elaborate on the larger picture so we can help you figure out what you're looking for?

Comment: @AaronDufour, it's for the purposes of a class, unfortunately all I'm concerned about is the amount of comparisons so that I may have some sort of answer if this comes up on the test.

Comment: @Ceelos That's reasonable.  You haven't explicitly defined what a comparison means for the purpose of that class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count comparisons of your array, sometimes/always "a".  EG: "a[left] > a[i]".  You could add a counter for the comparisons as a global, and ++ it each time you do a comparison to get a comparison count.

BTW, heap sort is interesting theoretically, but it's not stable, and isn't generally as fast as timsort, nor does it take advantage of partially sorted data as well.

Comment: This was a better approach at the actual solution. Turns out that our typical heap sort algorithm sometimes misses or adds comparisons that we would do by hand. The answer was really dependent on a manual way of doing the algorithm rather than running it on a computer. Thank you for your input though, it gave me a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

You generally only count element comparisons, not integer comparisons, even though the elements in your array are integers.

To make this make a bit more sense - if you were to change the array to an array of strings (for example), only count the number of string comparisons. String comparisons are generally way more expensive than integer comparisons (and it would be even more so if you have a large object with many fields), so only counting these makes sense.

So these compare elements:

```
a[left] > a[i]
a[right] > a[largest]
```

These just compare integers:

```
i >= 0
left <= n
right <= n
largest != i
i > 0
```

I'd suggest writing a `compare` function that also increases your count (and just replacing the above 2 element comparisons with it and removing other places where you increase the count). I also suggest sticking to [convention](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare%28int,%20int%29) in what the function returns.

Your function can just look like this: (pre-Java 7 you'll have to use `Integer.valueOf(a).compareTo(b)` instead)

```
int compare(int a, int b)
{
  counter++;
  return Integer.compare(a, b);
}
```

So `a[left] > a[i]` would become `compare(a[left], a[i]) > 0`, and similarly for the other one.

A [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) would make for a more generic solution, but it is probably a bit overkill in this case.